# VBA - Argument not optional, I don't get why

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a mini mileage app using VBA and I think I'm nearly finished although I don't understand what it means "argument not optional".

When I press the button I get the error:

> Compile error: Argument not optional

**Sheet 3**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("E6").Value = 0.23
End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call allinone
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Range("D5").Value = 0.35

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then Range("F5").Value = 0.15

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

**Module**

```
Function allinone(miles As Integer, cartype As Integer) As Single
Dim miles As Integer, vat As Integer, total As Single


    Const owncar_rate = 0.35
    Const cocar_rate = 0.15
    Const vatrate = 0.23
    Dim mileage As Single, vat As Single

    If Range("E2") = 1 Then
        mileage = Range("D5") * Range("E7")
    Else
        mileage = Range("F5") * Range("E7")
    End If
    If Range("E7") = 1 Then
        vat = Range("E6") * Range("E7")
    Else
        vat = 0
    End If
    Range("D10").Value = miles
    Range("D11").Value = vat
    Range("D12").Value = total
    allinone = mileage + vat

End Function
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Use Single step (F8)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Call allinone
```

`allinone` has parameters, but you're not passing in any arguments when you call it.  Hence the error.

What you need is something like

```
 allinone milesValue, carTypeValue
```

(it's best to avoid `Call` - it's outdated and deprecated)

Also, you can delare a variable `miles` inside your sub if you already have a parameter with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The function `allinone` takes 2 arguments:

```
Function allinone(miles As Integer, cartype As Integer) As Single
```

It is called here without any argument:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call allinone
End Sub
```

Thus, there is an error. To avoid the error, add some arguments when calling:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    allinone 2, 4
End Sub
```

Comment: This is because the function returns a value, but does not write it anywhere. Write `MsgBox allinone (2,4)` instead of `allinone 2,4` and something should happen.

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately not

Comment: Most probably the button is associated with the wrong sub. Delete the button. Then create the button from scratch, see what code the click provides and put `MsgBox allinone (2,4)` into it. It could work.

Comment: Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox allinone(2, 4)
End Sub

New button created... yet nothing. Thanks again

Comment: Did you put the `MsgBox allinone(2,4)` in the new button code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your other array

```
Dim miles as Integer, vat as Integer, total as Single
Dim cartype as Integer
```